# How can I limit DBeaver Data Editor to limit result set size?

Tags: sql, configuration, ide, amazon-redshift, dbeaver

How can I limit DBeaver Data Editor to limit the result set size?

I know the default is 200 and we can configure it in settings/preferences for the "Data Editor" section but this filter seems to be applied after all the results are already fetched from remote DataBase to local.

[image]

How can I limit this 200 before sending the request to the Database itself?

Meaning, instead of issuing a "Select * from..." to the Databases and doing the 200 results set a filter on local, I want to configure DBeaver to send "Select * from... LIMIT 200" to remote DB.

Answer (score 29):

By checking the "Use SQL to limit fetch size" check box you should get the effect you want.

[image]

You can verify DBeaver is behaving the way you expect by taking a look at the query in the DBeaver *execution log*. You will see `LIMIT` has been appended to your SQL query.

[image]

https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/SQL-Editor#results-panel

---

### Other things to consider

It's probably worth noting that you may also want to consider de-selecting the "Refresh data on next page reading" option or the "Auto-fetch next segment" option if you want to guarantee `LIMIT` is always selecting the set amount of rows. With both of these options turned on in addition to "Use SQL to limit fetch size", DBeaver will rerun the full result set as you scroll through your data and pass the last row.

For example, when you execute the query the first time it will run with `LIMIT 0, 200`, returning the first two hundred rows. When you scroll past row 200, a new query will be executed, with `LIMIT 0, 400`. When you pass row 400 a new query will be run with `LIMIT 0, 600` and so on.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I instead set the Result Set Fetch Size = 0

Comment: @TomRenish setting the Fetch Size to 0 will have the effect of cancelling the fetch size limit. The above answer works

Comment: I couldn't find this configuration in later versions of DBeaver.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It is still present in the latest version (**version 23.3.1** at the time of writing this) of DBeaver. Open "Settings > Editors > Data Editor" - everything is still there for the **global** configuration. But you can also configure a specific connection by right-clicking it and selecting "Edit connection" (or using the F4 shortcut). In the opened dialog window again select "Data Editor" and check the "Datasource <your_connection_name> settings" checkbox. This way you can configure only this specific connection the way you want.